# Double action form send user input to both email and new page

Tags: php, html, forms, scripting

I wish to use a single HTML form to send the user's input to my email, and simultaneously a web page that the user views their input. At present I can only get one of the two options; the web page re-direct which displays the users input.

Is there a back-side PHP script to accomplish sending the user input to both an email and a web page?

Form code:

```
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="TEST.php">

        <input name="name" type="text" class="formdetail" id="name" />

        <input name="color" type="text" class="formdetail" id="color" size="45"/>

        <input name="animal" type="text" class="formdetail" id="animal" size="45"/>

        <input name="room" type="text" class="formdetail" id="room" size="45"/>

        <input name="water" type="text" class="formdetail" id="water" size="45"/>

        <input name="email2" type="text" class="formdetail" id="email" size="45"/>

        <input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit" value="Submit" />

         <input type="hidden" name="recipients" value="http://www.Website.net/TEST.php" />

      <input type="hidden" name="good_url" value="http://www.Website.net/TEST.php" />


    </form>
```

Results web page page code:

```
      <p>Your results, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>:</p>

      <p>1. Your favorite color reveals: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['color']); ?>.</p>

      <p>2. Your favorite animal reveals: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['animal']); ?>.</p>


      <p>3. This reveals: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['room']); ?>.</p>

      <p>4. This reveals: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['water']); ?>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding your question correctly you want that script to send the user on to the next page after it emails you?

It's really very simple :)

First, you need to store your data into some persistent store, such as a session using start_session() on your first page. This will allow you to store data in the $_SESSION super global. Then on your next page after using:

```
http_redirect($newUrl);
```

You can grab the session data using that same superglobal

Place that after your email code and you should be good to go. If you're asking something a little different please don't hesitate to call me out and we can figure this thing out.

For reference: [http_redirect() in a nutshell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php)
And: [php sessions in a nutshell](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I'm seeking a script which will send the user's input to both me (in an email) and to the the redirected web page. I'm not seeking a re-direct script.

Comment: I realized I had left something out in my answer, checkout the edit.

Comment: Thanks. I'm out of my comprehension league here. I don't know anything about start_session() or superglobal. I work in entertainment; where smart phones overwhelm. I'll keep reading this and try to have it make sense to me. Thanks, again.

Comment: Sure thing, and please make sure to read up on sessions. That's how most of the Internet works, and it's going to save you a lot of trouble in the long run, especially with persisting data across script executions :)